# How to use multiprocess in openpyxl object?

Tags: openpyxl

I need to deal with a excel with many sheet in it, but every sheet have large data.If use openpyxl to load this excel, that will spend a lot of time,so I want to analysis each sheet by multiprocess.

the brief code like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import openpyxl
def LoadEx():
        wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
        sheetnames=wb.get_sheet_names()
        return sheetnames, wb

def job(sheet,wb):
    gs=wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)
    for i in range(10):
        if gs.cell(row=i,column=2).value=='Target':
            gs.cell(row=i,column=3).value='OK'

if __name__=='__main__':
    sheetnames,wb=LoadEx()
    pool=mp.Pool()
    for sheetname in sheetnames:
        res=pool.apply_async(job, (sheetname,wb))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    wb.save('example_output.xlsx')
```

but,the file 'example_output.xlsx' seem not to save the job()'s result,
How should i do to obtain  multiprocess's effect in this case? 
may someone could help me, thinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `multiprocessing`, but you have to *pay* for it.

1. The `global wb` become a **copy** for every `process` you use.
   Therefore using 4 `processes`, your *memory* have to be large enough to hold 4 copies of your Workbook.
2. Given that `wb` is a copy, your changes belong to this copy.
   You have to copy your changes into **one** Workbook.
   Copying Worksheets could be time consuming.

To overcome the Pickling Error, I changed from doing queueing `ws` to `wsDiff`.
Instead of writing to the `ws` copy, aggreate changes to `wsDiff`.
As a bonus, copy to target `wb` will be faster.

> Time table: cpu_count=2, 10 Worksheets, workload: `def ws_job(...`

```
Job Processes   without mp           2               4  
Time          0:00:21.260746  0:00:10.214942  0:00:07.097369
```

This working example will fit for the given Question `def job`.
, for instance:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import queue, os, time
import random as rd
import openpyxl


class wsDiff(object):
    def __init__(self, row, column, value):
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        self.value = value


def ws_job(wb, ws_idx):
    ws = wb.worksheets[ws_idx]
    print('pid %s: process (%s)' % (os.getpid(), ws.title))

    # *** DO SOME STUFF HERE***
    # Simulate workload
    time.sleep(rd.randrange(1, 4))

    diff = []
    for i in range(1, 11):
        if ws.cell(row=i, column=2).value == 'Target':
            #ws.cell(row=i, column=3).value = 'OK'
            diff.append( wsDiff(i, 3, 'OK') )

    return diff


def job(fq, q, wb):
    while True:
        try:
            ws_idx = fq.get_nowait()
        except queue.Empty:
            print('pid %s: exit job' % os.getpid())
            exit(0)

        q.put((ws_job(wb, ws_idx), ws_idx))
        time.sleep(0.1)


def writer(q, wb):
    print('start writer_handler')
    while True:
        try:
            diff, i_ws = q.get()
        except ValueError:
            print('writer ValueError exit(1)')
            exit(1)

        if diff == None:
            wb.save('../test/example_output.xlsx')
            exit(0)

        ws = wb.worksheets[i_ws]
        print('pid %s: update sheet %s from diff' % (os.getpid(), ws.title))
        for d in diff:
            ws.cell(row=d.row, column=d.column).value = d.value


def mpRun():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('../test/example.xlsx')

    f_q = mp.Queue()
    for i in range(len(wb.worksheets)):
        f_q.put(i)

    w_q = mp.Queue()
    w_p = mp.Process(target=writer, args=(w_q, wb))
    w_p.start()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    pool = [mp.Process(target=job, args=(f_q, w_q, wb)) for p in range(os.cpu_count() + 2)]
    for p in pool:
        p.start()
        time.sleep(0.1)

    for p in pool:
        p.join()

    time.sleep(0.2)
    # Terminate Process w_p after all Sheets done
    w_q.put((None, None))
    w_p.join()

    print('EXIT __main__')
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1 - LibreOffice:4.3.3.2***

Comment: Thanks for stovfl's reply, This help me a lot.
but when i try to run the code it will appear
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument:'worksheet', and seem in endless loop ,can't exit , how could i fix it?

Comment: WOW! It work now, you are really amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Workbooks are not suited for multiprocessing as there is a lot of shared state.

Comment: Get it, I will try other method,thank for your help!